# React App - materialize-css doesn't initialize on first render

Tags: reactjs, materialize

I am building a 'Add Item' functionality with React and materialize-css. For some reason, the materialize-css components are not being initialized when i first navigate into the page they are on. They do initilize though after I refresh the page. I spent several hours trying to figure out the problem but couldn't find what i did wrong. I installed materialize-css via npm and here is my code where i initiliaze the materialize-css components:

```
    componentDidMount() {
    var context = this;
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

        var elemsTwo = document.querySelectorAll('select');
        var instancesTwo = M.FormSelect.init(elemsTwo, {});

        var elemsThree = document.querySelectorAll('.timepicker');
        var instancesThree = M.Timepicker.init(elemsThree, {});
      });
}
```

Like I said it does work fine after refreshing the page, but when just navigating into the page, it doesn't work. Below are the screenshots on how the page looks before and after refreshing (refer to fields 'Gender' and 'Spoken Languages' on screenshots). Thanks in advance.

[image: After]

[image: Before]

Comment: Checkout this article for how to correctly use Materialize with React, without having to depend on 3rd party libraries https://medium.com/@mattdlockyer/youre-using-materialize-css-wrong-470b593e78e9

Comment: thanks very much for the link. i will look into it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bad practice to use React while using `DOMContentLoaded` on your own. Your main problem is, that `DOMContentLoaded` is fired when your content is ready, but this does not mean that React has done its initialisation. Also, `DOMContentLoaded` is not fired when you navigate between pages using React.

You may use a library that already closes this gap, like https://material-ui.com/.

---

If you want to stay with your concept, you have to call the code you run in your `componentDidMount` also when your navigator changed the page.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. i will look into this :)

Comment: Feel free to accept this answer if you are happy! :-)